# Python / Pygame TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, variables, fonts, pygame

I want to display a font on the top left with an update-able score. But it shows an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Mäse\workspace\Snake\src\snake_game__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       score_display = font.render("Score: %d"(score), 1, BLACK)
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Here's my code:

```
>    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 16)
>    score = 0
>    score_display = font.render("Score: %d"(score), 1, BLACK
```

It's not the whole code, just the part you need. I know how to blit the text, I just get the error when I do it this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"Score: %d"(score)
```

Should be

```
"Score: %d" % score
```

Or, better:

```
"Score: {0}".format(score)
```